# Is there any way to display child pages alphabetically in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function

I want to display WordPress Child pages in alphabetical order. Is there any way to do this

Answer (score 0):

In your function you should put something like this:

```
        <?php $args=array(
          'post_parent' => 11202,
          'post_type' => 'page',
          'orderby' => 'title',
        );
```

Then you will get the posts in Alphabetical order